# Deleting rows in a listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have this code

```
rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim a = MsgBox("Unstuck?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirmation")
    If a = vbYes Then
        For I = 0 To ListViewAccounts.CheckedItems.Count Step -1
            rs.Open("Select * From tb_registration WHERE st_acc_number='" & ListViewAccounts.SelectedItems(I).SubItems(I).Text & "'", cn, 0, 3)
            rs.Fields("st_log").Value = "out"
            rs.Update()
            rs.Close()
            MsgBox("Accounts unstucked", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
            ListViewAccounts.Items.Clear()
            Call AccountList()
        Next

        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This deleted a selected row in a listview, now what I want to do is to have a check box in each row and delete multiple row with 1 button click based on how many checked rows I checked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: for starters, dont clear all the items **inside** a loop iterating the rows, then if you want to delete, dont use a SELECT query. Dont use `Step-1` to go forwards in a loop.  If you are iterating `CheckedItems` dont use an index into `SelectedItems` - they are not the same thing. Whatever AccountList does, you probably dont want to do it until all the delete/unstuck candidates are handled.  I am not sure "unstuck" means delete, but that is a start

Comment: i forgot to include something. this are the rows of my listview account#/name/course/status/log the list are from my database, now for log i have in and out, there are some account#s with in and out on the log column, what i want to do is, to changed the ones with in to out using the checkbox so that i will not change them 1 by 1.

Comment: ...then use an UPDATE query, not a SELECT. all the other comment still apply. (you will have to do it 1 by 1 - in a loop - if it is not bound to the database)  9 Questions : 6 Answers : **0** Accepted.  you should accept answers which help when people take the time

Comment: I'm new to this site, how can I accept answers? or flag. i'm still familiarizing the functions of the site, can you enlighten me?

Comment: your old questions are listed on your profile...just visit them and click the UP arrow for any and all that helped, click the CHECK for the answer that fixed the problem  [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/about)